# How to get mouse clicks to draw a rectangle on an image in opencv?

Tags: c++, c, opencv

In opencv, I am displaying some image on the screen.  I want to be able to click with the mouse and draw a rectangle around an object.

For example, let's say I have an image of a newspaper, and I want to draw a rectangle to connect the 4 corners of the front-page image of that newspaper to replace it with a different image.  How can this be done in opencv?